_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL mismatch for one file in project
I am trying to compile my C++ project in Visual Studio Community 2022 (v143) with amqpcpp library but with no success.
I have built amqpcpp library file using instructions on their github page and imported amqpcpp.lib to Visual Studio linker and included headers for the compiler. Visual Studio recognized the new library and Intellisense is working properly with it.
When it comes to compiling I get multiple errors stating the same description

Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Assembly.obj    IntegratorWorkflow  C:\Users\user\source\repos\IntegratorWorkflow\amqpcpp.lib(field.obj)

For multiple files of amqpcpp.lib I get the same error, the only difference is the file name at the end
My project was compiling properly with the Debug option from the start but only after including amqpcpp.lib I get an error.
I tried to compile this library using "COMPILE_FLAGS_DEBUG "/D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2" option in CMakeList.txt but still i got the same error.
I also checked all files in my project if any are set for Release mode but got nothing.
Maybe someone could help me resolve this issue. I'm glad for any help.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL -- as with most macros beginning with an underscore, you shouldn't define them yourself...

It was just for test purposes however I still got an error so I do not know how that's relevant

Check you are linking debug with debug and release with release and not crossing them over.

If you did cmake --build . --target install that would likely create the debug version of the library. You can't use it in a release application in msvc it can only be used in a debug application.

Okay I figured it out. My Visual Studio Project has had declared _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0 in Preprocessor Definitions for some reason. Removing this fixed the issue

Make sure your not mixing debug and release, Meaning you can't use a debug library in a release application or a release library in a debug one. The reason I tell you is this will create undefined behavior even if you force the macro value.

If this solves your problem, consider accept it.
